# Data in Contact selector disappearing after the selection of business account

Tags: acumatica

I am just having a simple selector for contacts in my custom sreen. User can choose the Business Account, Prospect, customer.. and the related contacts should load to the selector. Below is my selector DAC definition.

I found weird that the Selector loads data for the first 2 Business account selection, After that for all subsequent selection the contact information is not available. If i rebuild my project again this data appears. Looks like some additional conditions are getting appended. But i am not sure what is going wrong. Please assist.

```
 #region ContactOpportunity
        public abstract class contactOpportunity : PX.Data.IBqlField { }     
        [PXDBInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Contact")]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search2<Contact.contactID,
               InnerJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Contact.bAccountID>>>,
               Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<UsrQuotation.baccountOpportunity>>,
                    And<Contact.isActive, Equal<True>>>>),
               SubstituteKey = typeof(Contact.displayName), Filterable = true)]
        public virtual Int32? ContactOpportunity { get; set; }
 #endregion
```

Comment: I've tried to reproduce described issue using code provided. However, it seems to work fine. Could you please provide more details?

Comment: @DmitryNaumov Its a strange issue, as i mentioned in the Question, it will work for the first 2 times only when i select a BAccount for one more time then contacts is empty. However, it works after i used the DAC BAccountCRM

Comment: Well, it sounds like some cache issue. Maybe it is something related to cache initialization sequence. Anyway, full code of the business object is required to investigate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who encounter similar issue,

After i change the DAC to **BAccountCRM** it works as usual. I dont know what actually happens when i use the other DAC.

```
 #region ContactOpportunity
        public abstract class contactOpportunity : PX.Data.IBqlField { }     
        [PXDBInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Contact")]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search2<Contact.contactID,
               InnerJoin<BAccountCRM, On<BAccountCRM.bAccountID, Equal<Contact.bAccountID>>>,
               Where<BAccountCRM.bAccountID, Equal<Current<UsrQuotation.baccountOpportunity>>,
                    And<Contact.isActive, Equal<True>>>>),
               SubstituteKey = typeof(Contact.displayName), Filterable = true)]
        public virtual Int32? ContactOpportunity { get; set; }
 #endregion
```